# Reversing matrix indices in Python

Tags: python, matrix, iteration

I have the following 3 x 3 matrix:

| Zone | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 200 | 140 |
| B | 200 | 0 | 60 |
| C | 140 | 60 | 0 |

When looping over this matrix, I want to first retrieve an unequal index pair and then the reverse of this pair. So for example, i'd want to retrieve row 1, column 2 (1,2) and then row 2, column (2,1). I'd want to continue this pattern throughout the entire matrix. How could I approach this?

Comment: What are the corresponding values of Row 1 Column 2 and Row 2 Column 1?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
matrix = [[0, 200, 140],[200, 0, 60],[140, 60, 0]]

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        if i != j:
            pair1 = matrix[i][j]
            pair2 = matrix[j][i]
            print(pair1, pair2) #for reference
```